# Backbone.JS: custom url for a function of a model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I make a function on my model called 'post' and i want to send a request to the server via POST request thru a custom url(sample below). How can i set the url without affecting the rootUrl to send the request? TIA!

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: '../mymodel'
    initialize: function(){

    },
    post: function(){
        // how put the url here?
        // this is the custom url: '../post/mymodel/' + this.model.get('id')
        // this is the expected log on server:
        // POST: ../post/mymodel/323133 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `url` instead of `urlRoot`

Note that `model.url` delegates to `model.collection.url` unless it is otherwise specified

Read more about [`model.url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax:

```
post: function(){ 
    $.post('../post/mymodel/' + this.model.get('id'), function(data) {
        $(".result").html(data);
    });
}
```